# Uploading a file problem with Alamofire Swift 5?

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-upload

I want to upload a simple file using,

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'
```

But I cannot see the file in the linux host's folder.

**upload.php file:**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)===false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

**Swift file:**

```
    func upload(image: UIImage,
                progressCompletion: @escaping (_ percent: Float) -> Void,
                completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
        print("Could not get JPEG representation of UIImage")
        return
      }

      AF.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
          multipartFormData.append(imageData,
                                   withName: "imagefile",
                                   fileName: "image.jpg",
                                   mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        to: "http://website.com/upload.php", usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), method: .post)

        .uploadProgress { progress in
             progressCompletion(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))
        }
        .response { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func getStartedBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        upload(
            image: UIImage(named: "uploadFile.png")!,
          progressCompletion: { [weak self] percent in
            guard let _ = self else {
              return
            }
            print("Status: \(percent)")
          },
          completion: { [weak self] result in
            guard let _ = self else {
              return
            }
        })
    }
```

**When use to: area in Swift code as "https://httpbin.org/post":**

```
Status: 1.0
...
[Data]: 19034 bytes
[Network Duration]: 0.9285140037536621s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(Optional(19034 bytes))
```

**For my custom website's upload.php the result is:**

```
Status: 1.0
...
[Data]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.3820209503173828s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(nil)
```

**Even simplest block from Alamofire:**

```
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "uploadFile", withExtension: "png") {
            AF.upload(fileURL, to: "http://website.com/upload.php").responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        }
```

**I'm getting inputDataNilOrZeroLength error:**

```
[Request Body]: 
None
[Response]: 
[Status Code]: 200
[Headers]:
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 06:19:32 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Vary: User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.20
[Response Body]: 
None
[Data]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.33376002311706543s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0014129877090454102s
[Result]: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength))
```

**At the top of upload.php works from web with below page:**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find a way even simple file uploadings. What I'm missing that point? It would be great if someone explain it.

Later on, I should **configure it for uploading video files** too. Is there any configuration advices for that?

Comment: In multipartFormData,  can you try changing the filed  `withName: "imagefile"` to  `withName: "image"`

Comment: @Sayooj Great it works now. I want to ask some more details. CHMOD permission is "775" for my uploads folder. Is it logic or should I take another action for security? I will take "https", another action etc. Also how can I configure that for video files too? If you have knowledge about them please share as detailed answer. I will appreciate.

Comment: I'm no expert :) , 775 is an ideal permission as far i know. You can also add additional security by allowing only authenticated users to access the uploaded files [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328243/6677134) and prevent direct access to files via URL [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename you look for in server is `$_FILES['image']` and the file name you send with request is `imagefile`.Try changing the `multipartFormData` appending to as follows

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData,
                         withName: "image",
                         fileName: "image.jpg",
                         mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Comment: I've using multipart and forget rename withName: "image", you save my day thank you a lot